Geometry nodes use displacement from Raycasted object material
I was wondering if the following can be done.
I have a geometry nodes setup for a plane, using Raycast and mesh subdivision to "project" an object (ie: a cube) to the plane and get a "basrelief" moving the plane vertex in Z.
It works fine, now I was wondering if I can use the normals or something from the Cube's material bump as height.
I have something drawn in the cube faces that bumps and shows the drawings in relief. I would like to pass that "cube's relief" info to the raycasted cube on the plane (it may be for any other bumping of the material).
I can raycast and get the cube (object) "projected" on the plane, but it will be great if I can "raycast" the bumping of the object.
Can this be done?
This is the setup. The Lines in the cube are a bump height displacement material. I want these drawing to be casted too.


i highly recommend to provide sketches/images to make it more clear, what you want to achieve. Also providing your node tree and a blend file would attract more people.

I think the only way is to convert the bumps into an image first and then use a texture to add to the offset.

But this would not have the cube & texture point of view/Cast"... :-(
